# Custom AuthorizationFilterAttribute not firing at all

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, authorize-attribute

Followign [this](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/18/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-Authorization-Filter) blog, I've implemented Basic Authorization filter. I've registered it like below.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Filters.Add(new BasicAuthenticationFilter());
    }
}
```

As that it not working, I tried registering it in `Global.asax`.

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
   protected void Application_Start()
   {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new BasicAuthenticationFilter());
    }

}
```

But both of the registration is not working, `OnAuthorization` is not at calling.

I have used `System.Web.Http.Filters` Version `5.2.3.0`

Any Ideas?

**API Config:**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.Filters.Add(new BasicAuthenticationFilter());

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you testing that it is not working? Make sure the the controller(s) you call to test don't have `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute. The first config setup you have should be enough, no need to add the second one.

Comment: It is not having that attribute. and one more doubt, Do I need to enable `Anonymous Authentication` in `IIS`

Comment: I'm still trying to understand your issue given the information you have presented. How are you testing that it is not working. What controller are you trying to get to. show it. is your configuration set up properly. I'm assuming that the sample you showed is just a simple example of your api setup. No? have you set up your routes?

Comment: @Nkosi Pls check my updates

Comment: are you able to browse to your controller actions? show an example of a request. saying it doesn't work is not very helpful. What are you doing and what is the expectation of what you do that would show that it works. Yes you say the `OnAuthorization` is not calling, but are you able to verify that you are able to call an api controller successfully? Help us to help you. be clear in what you are doing. that way the problem can be recreated and a possible solution found. Show the action you are testing on. show the url of the action you are testing with.

Comment: How come if authorization fails I wil be able to browse controller methods ?

Comment: If auth was failing you would not have been allowed to view the resource.

Comment: Ok here's the thing. You say you are following an example that you linked to in your post. Show the code you have written so far. test it by applying it to one controller as a test case. and then try browsing to that controller. Otherwise you may need to either completely rewrite this question or delete it and start a new question that better explains what you did and the problem you are facing. You are just not providing enough information to get the help you seek IMO.

Answer (score 0):

The Authentication in IIS should be set up as follows
[image: IIS Authentication]

Comment: You can flag the post for undeletion once you edit it, instead of editing it with meta remarks or posting another answer.